# Convert Parameters to Base64 Encoded String for API Call using Alamofire

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire, swift4

I am trying to track an event in my OS X app using Mixpanel. Here are their API docs: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http#tracking-via-http

I am trying to send an even with an event name and a bunch of properties. One of the properties is the token as seen in the docs. It looks like I need to convert the parameters to a string and then base64 encode them. What is the best way to do this?

I am using Alamofire for this and the Parameters are Alamofire Parameters.

These are the requirements for Base64 encoding for Mixpanel

```
To Base64 encode data for the Mixpanel API, you should use the following characters:

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789+/=

Mixpanel will only accept padded Base64 requests.
```

Here is my code so far. I just don't know how to base64 encode parameters.

```
var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "content-type": "application/json"
]

var parameters:Parameters = [String : Any]()
parameters["event"] = "hello world"

var properties = [String:String]
props["token"] = "INSERT_TOKEN_HERE"
parameters["properties"] = properties

var url = "http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=\()" //after the data= is where the base64 encoded parameters are supposed to go

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: nil , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):
        print ("return: \(value)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print ("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, MixPanel has their own iOS SDK that would appear to get you out of the weeds of building their funky requests. https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/swift

Comment: So the issue with their iOS SDK is that it does not support OS X apps. I use the iOS SDK for iOS apps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the `data` from their example:

```
http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=eyJldmVudCI6ICJnYW1lIiwgInByb3BlcnRpZXMiOiB7ImlwIjogIjEyMy4xMjMuMTIzLjEyMyIsICJkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICIxMzc5MyIsICJ0b2tlbiI6ICJlM2JiNDEwMDMzMGMzNTcyMjc0MGZiOGM2ZjVhYmRkYyIsICJ0aW1lIjogMTI0NTYxMzg4NSwgImFjdGlvbiI6ICJwbGF5In19
```

So we can examine that like so:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: "eyJldmVudCI6ICJnYW1lIiwgInByb3BlcnRpZXMiOiB7ImlwIjogIjEyMy4xMjMuMTIzLjEyMyIsICJkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICIxMzc5MyIsICJ0b2tlbiI6ICJlM2JiNDEwMDMzMGMzNTcyMjc0MGZiOGM2ZjVhYmRkYyIsICJ0aW1lIjogMTI0NTYxMzg4NSwgImFjdGlvbiI6ICJwbGF5In19")
let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
print(string)
```

And that shows us their JSON structure:

```
{
    "event": "game",
    "properties": {
        "ip": "123.123.123.123",
        "distinct_id": "13793",
        "token": "e3bb4100330c35722740fb8c6f5abddc",
        "time": 1245613885,
        "action": "play"
    }
}
```

So we can then write code to build a similar structure ourselves:

```
let dictionary: [String : Any] = [
    "event": "hello world",
    "properties": [
        "token": "INSERT_TOKEN_HERE"
    ]
]

let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)
let base64Representation = data.base64EncodedString()
let parameters = ["data": base64Representation]

let url = "http://api.mixpanel.com/track/"

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print("return:", value)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error:", error)
        }
}
```

Note, I set this up as a `GET` (because it looks like the entire request is in the URL), and I used `URLEncoding` because Alamofire is not building a JSON body. Also, I got rid of the `headers` stuff, as you should always just let Alamofire take care of that sort of stuff for you when possible.

Comment: Awesome that worked! These were the two lines I needed `let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary); let base64Representation = data.base64EncodedString()` Thanks for all the other notes as well. I made those changes. What is the difference between URLEncoding and JSONEncoding? I also removed the parameters field and just did it like this `let url = "https://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=\(base64Representation)"` Is that ok?

Comment: `URLEncoding` encodes the request in a URL, and `JSONEncoding` builds a JSON request and puts it in the body of a request. But because of MixPanel's weird API, you have to do the JSON encoding yourself, and base64 encode that into a URL. Hence `URLEncoding`. In answer to building the URL yourself, that's a bit fragile and not recommended. I'd rather let Alamofire do that for you. What if the base64-encoded string had a `+` in it: That's a special character on many web services and can't just be put in a URL without encoding that (though maybe MixPanel accepts it). It's up to you.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much!